# Stop Visual Studio from running JS tests on build

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gruntjs, karma-runner

My Visual Studio (2015) seems to have started running our full JS test suite at a variety of points, including (I think?) on-solution-open and post-build.

It's outputting into the "Output Window", under the "Tests" dropdown.
It's producing an output along the lines of:

```
------ Discover test started ------

< ... Test output ... >

========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:05.9645562) ==========
------ Discover test started ------

< ... Test output ... >

========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:04.589261) ==========
------ Discover test started ------

< ... Test output ... >

========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:05.0128855) ==========
------ Discover test started ------

... etc.
```

As it happens the test output are all trivial "Can't find variable 'define'" errors. However, this isn't the point, since **I don't want VS to be doing this!**

It's not something that anyone on the team deliberately configured, and we can't find any setting for it anywhere.

Normally we run our JS tests on the commandline via karma and/or grunt.

Any idea what has caused this and how to stop it?

Comment: Does the VS _Task Runner Explorer_ tool not show any config for these tasks which are unexpectedly running?

Comment: @RobC TRE sucessfully maps the Grunt file, but asserts there are no bindings for any of the tasks.

Comment: I suspect this of being related to the Chutzpah VS plugin. Unconfirmed, will update once we've had a chance to see whether it's completely gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the 2 chutzpah VS plugins that I had installed has stopped this.
I imagine these had been installed as part of another project, and simply weren't compatible with this project.

Possibly there were configurations with the plugins that would have solved it too, but I haven't looked